# How to emulate the behavior of master page in Net.Core and VS Code

Tags: html, asp.net-core

When building an MVC project, there's a shared folder automatically provided in which I have *Layout.cshtml* page that's used like the holder or master page (as it was called in Web Forms). So, all the banners, navbars, footers etc. go in there, while the acutal pages being developed refer to it in the source code and got pasted together upon rendition. This far I'm following.

Now, I have a set up and AspNet website using Yeoman and the only thing I have is *wwwroot* directory in which I put the file *start.html*. (It's the same as *index.html* - I just wanted to try out if I have full control over default files.)

I'm unsure how to proceed. I.e. I'd like the links on the *start.html* to point to files like *uno.html*, *duo.html* etc. and read those into a designated part of the landing page (i.e. *start.html*).

Is it doable without using the magic of templates? I want to have full control over the rendition process.

There's no point googling it, I noticed, because anything I've got the last two hours leads to *how to create master page* not to *how to emulate master page*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the static files middleware is just for that: static files.

You roughly have two options:

1. Do everything client sided, i.e. rather than having normal links use javascript/ajax calls and embed the content of the static file in your start.html using javascript.

   It should work, but has several down-sites like it requires javascript to work (not a big issue these days, except for the paranoids who use no-script browser extensions) and that web crawler still may have issues properly indexing ajax heavy web pages
2. Wait until [ASP.NET Core 1.2 (scheduled for Q1-Q2 2017)](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap), which will add Razor Pages. Pages rendered with Razor template engine, but without the need of a controller.

   > ### 1.2
   >
   > - WebSockets
   > - SignalR
   > - Razor Pages (Views without MVC controllers)
   > - Web API security
3. If you don't wanna wait, try RazorLight, which is 3rd party open source library for rendering Razor views.

But all except the first one require some "magic template engine".

You could of course write an [server-sided includes (SSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) middleware which would be based on `UseStaticFiles` middleware and parse the file and include the html files server sided before returning it. There is nothing out of the box for it as far as I know.

Comment: I'm tempted to try (1). Are you suggesting that hte landing page would have a div with id *holder1* and then a JS that would read in e.g. *about-html* and append its contents to the *holder1* div? In such case, I only need to figure out how to intercept calls to pages that do not exist and generate the partial based on the url requested and jack it into the landing page, right? Suggestions on how to do such an interception? I'm sensing *app.Run(async (context) => { await context.Response.WriteAsync(...)* is my friend there?

Comment: Yea, that's the basic idea. Not sure what you mean with partials if you not gonna use Razor views at all. The "partial" files would be just static html files lying inside wwwroot